# Issues mounting external FAT32 HDD in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive

I've looked through previous threads, as well as google, but haven't been able to find a working solution yet.

I'm trying to connect an external HDD to my pc. I'm running ubuntu from a live USB, and am trying to copy files from my windows 8 documents folder to the external hdd. Afterwards, I intend to completely remove windows and do a clean install of ubuntu. However, I am unable to open the external HDD, because

> Unable to access “Ext Harde Schijf 1”
>
> Error creating mount point `/media/ubuntu/Ext Harde Schijf 1': Read-only file system

I've tried unmounting and mounting manually, and I've tried changing permissions. I copy-pasted my terminal entries at the end of this post.
I would really like to not have to format the hdd, as it served as my back-up, and I have important files on there.

What am I missing here? Does anyone have any ideas?

fdisk -l results:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xee5ec694

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848  2930274303  1464777728    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdf: 3985 MB, 3985637376 bytes
123 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1020 cylinders, total 7784448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004872f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1   *          62     7778519     3889229    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sdg: 1000.2 GB, 1000204883968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525164 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4aa5068b
```

Terminal inputs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/loop1
mount: mount point /media/ubuntu/70d8e54c-39ce-4caf-baa4-1eb5df2cd280 does not exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo unmount /dev/loop1
sudo: unmount: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ unmount
No command 'unmount' found, did you mean:
 Command 'umount' from package 'mount' (main)
unmount: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdf1
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdc1
umount: /dev/sdc1: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I went into 'disks', and was able to open and edit the mount options. I changed the filesystem type to 'auto' and saved. Hit 'mount' and lo and behold, it worked.

I was so caught up trying to find a way to do it by the terminal, I forgot to try the obvious.